# I can't seem to get my image to be absolute to the top of my page and cover the whole page

Tags: html, css

I have a background image for my site, it does cover the whole page but the problem is the image is getting pushed off the top and bottom instead of just the bottom.

Here is my HTML:

```
<img class="background" url="../images/splash.png" />
<div class="wrapper">
test
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
img.background{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:0
}
div.wrapper{
    margin-top:0;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Please make sure your image is enough large to cover the page! Your code seem fine. Also you're missing ";" end of z-index:0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give to `img`: `dispaly: block`, otherwise it won't listen to `width` and `height: 100%`.

**Update:**

```
img.background {
   position: fixed;
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean like so:
    img.background{
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        z-index:0;
        display:block;
    }
ahh sorry i don't know how to comment code here

Comment: I've got it! You should change in the `img` tag the `url` to `src`.